# Is is better to partition or create a new volume to keep and separate data from the core system in macOS?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, partitioning

I am new on macOS and I want to split disk to into two parts in order to keep my data files in the new part and just in case I need to reinstall my macOS. To prevent my files to be deleted.

For this purpose, I am looking at this this official Apple page: “[Partition a physical disk in Disk Utility on Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/disk-utility/dskutl14027/mac)”

But, I am not sure if creating volume instead of partition would be suitable for my scenario especially when I need to reinstall macOS to keep my files. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modern macOS versions inherently separate the core OS from system and user data by default.

#### No need to worry about this.

There is such an option in macOS to handle this without you needing to think about this.

If you simply reinstall macOS the data is left alone. Data in macOS Monterey is kept separate from the core OS. Start up the system in recovery mode and review the options. Look here at this [official Apple doc on this subject](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904). Specifically the “Reinstall macOS” section whose very first sentence is:

> “Reinstalling macOS does not remove data from your Mac.”

And as far as what is wiped out and what is retained, my understanding is that 100% anything that is *not* a part of the core OS files is retained.

It is a crazy new, and very useful, way of macOS handling this but I believe it can even retain config files and such.

It is purely an OS wipe like the way an iPhone wipe while retaining data works. Read [this official Apple doc](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210650) titled, “About the read-only system volume in macOS Catalina.”

While it refers to macOS Catalina, that is simply the first macOS to use this new setup. Any version of macOS from macOS Catalina to now (September 2022) works like this.

#### Cache and settings cleaning.

If your desire is to retain data but also resetting some core macOS settings that can be user adjusted, just download and install [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and use it to deep clean and reset macOS caches and rebuild deeper system libraries.

Another idea is to create a new user on the system and wipe out the old user; all user settings should be 100% clean then.

Comment: Yes, but in that case Mac also won't delete or reset some data that I want to delete while resetting. So, what if I want to keep some data (folder and files) while resetting Mac with removing all the apps and restting settings to initial state?

Comment: Download [Onyx](https://www.titanium-software.fr/en/onyx.html) and use it to deep clean and reset caches. Another idea is to create a new user on the system and wipe out the old user; all user settings should be 100% clean then.

Comment: Perfect answer, I installed it from now as it can also be used to increase system performance (I will need to use it before reset). Thanks a lot for your wonderful helps.

Answer (score 3):

What macOS are you using?
Modern macOS [Big Sur, Monterey] already does this; the System disk is read only & cannot be overwritten or interfered with even by an admin or root user without some very specific & 'dangerous' steps to disable the protection then re-calculate the secure checksum<sup>[1]</sup>. If the System detects any tampering, it will only boot into Recovery mode & will not allow any other operation except re-installing the OS.
This does not affect user data areas at all.

Even before that you haven't needed to nuke & pave a Mac in a very long time. You can always re-apply the same OS from Recovery if you're uncertain of its integrity.

macOS is not Windows XP. It doesn't get gradually worse over time, or need reinstalling every 6 months, just in case. There is absolutely no need.

<sup>[1]</sup>See [Can I mount the root (system) filesystem as writable in Big Sur?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395508/can-i-mount-the-root-system-filesystem-as-writable-in-big-sur)

Comment: Also, in my experience putting a user home folder on a different volume (different from the one macOS automatically creates & uses for user files, that is) *does* run a significant risk of causing trouble. So just don't do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply. I do not want to move any user or system files to a new volume/partition. Instead, I just want to keep there my personal documents, files, etc. So, for this purpose, what should I do? Should I create volume or partition? Mac is not Windows, I know, but what if I want to reset all the settings and setups while keeping my personal files? Just tell me the answer of it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: System files & user files are *already* on separate volumes, precisely for the purpose you describe; the ability to keep the system secure & allow simple reinstall without affecting user data. This idea of 'resetting' a Mac just isn't necessary until you sell it or give it away. You should always keep a backup anyway, before performing anything potentially 'dangerous' like re-partitioning. That task in itself has more chance of losing your data than simply allowing the system to look after itself.

Comment: Do you mean that when I reset my MAC (so not think the reason, just think that I want to reset everything on my MAC), only some parts or volumes are affected while some others are not and I can confidently keep my private data files and documents on these folders that won't be affected? If so, could you tell me what is the proper way to keep my private files, which location should I use for that purpose? I am sorry but as being new on Mac, I just wanted to make necessary settings and config from starting point. Thanks in advance for your useful helps.

Comment: Mac is really very unlike Windows. It doesn't demand you jump through hoops when you first get one, or have to reset it every five minutes. A new Mac arrives ready for maximum security & safety. There's nothing the user needs to do except setup a backup drive in case of emergency. Here are a couple of beginner's guides… https://www.macworld.com/article/227083/first-things-to-do-with-new-mac.html and https://www.imore.com/meet-your-new-mac